# SQL Server: Find Transaction Level of Previous Historical Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2019

How do I find the Transaction Level of Queries that have Previously run historical in SQL Server? This is only for currently running queries .

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/06/07/sql-server-how-to-know-transaction-isolation-level-for-each-session/

```
SELECT session_id, start_time, status,
total_elapsed_time,
CASE transaction_isolation_level
WHEN 1 THEN 'ReadUncomitted'
WHEN 2 THEN 'ReadCommitted'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable'
WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot'
ELSE 'Unspecified' END AS transaction_isolation_level,
sh.text, ph.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) sh
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) ph
```

Currently using Sql server 2019.

Comment: You need either Query Store or Extended Events. SQL Server does not track this historical queries otherwise

Comment: hi @Charlieface are you saying there are no sql DMVs that do this? thanks

Comment: I'm afraid not, unless you enable Query Store or use Extended Events, then you can pull it out of the plan XML

Comment: hi @Charlieface please put your comments as answer, and I can send points, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible under the standard configuration.

Your only options are

- create an Extended Event session that tracks it
- enable Query Store and read the information from the plans
- use the Profiler to setup a trace